# Count and group the results of a count

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I want the count the total amount of orders per email and then group the frequency of the results

If the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total
FROM orders
GROUP BY email 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Gives me

```
|--TOTAL--|
|    6    |
|    6    |
|    6    |
|    5    |
|    5    |
|    5    |
|    4    |
|    4    |
|    3    |
|    2    |
|---------|
```

How can I get this result

```
|--TOTAL--|--COUNT--|
|    6    |    3    |
|    5    |    3    |
|    4    |    2    |
|    3    |    1    |
|    2    |    1    |
|-------------------|
```

I essentially want to count the count

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT total, COUNT(total) AS frequency
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY email
) t
GROUP BY total
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Basically you do another aggregation by turning your original query into a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query as a subquery:

```
SELECT total, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as total
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY email
) t
GROUP BY total
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```